# how can I sorting strings with IF statement In RUBY

Tags: ruby, string, sorting, if-statement

This is codecademy`s test.

"Use .sort! to sort the fruits array in descending (that is, reverse) alphabetical order.
You can use the combined comparison operator (like the example above) or an if/elsif/else statement."

They give this array

```
fruits = ["orange", "apple", "banana", "pear", "grapes"]
```

I did it with this code

```
fruits.sort!{|i,j| j<=>i}
```

But couldn't solve this with 'IF statement'.

I tried everything I could for about 10 hours..

I`m new at RUBY and programming. Can anyone help me?

Comment: 10 hours? You are blatantly lying now aren't you?

Comment: I suggest you go read the documentation on the spaceship operator (`<=>`). If you understand what it does, it will be trivial to reimplement with if/else.

Comment: do you understand how the spaceship comparison (`<=>`) operator works? It returns one of 3 values -1,0,+1 for sorting ordinance. The `if` statement should be fairly easy from there.

Comment: Have you read any documentation for [`<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) or [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev @engineersmnky @muistoshort I know what spaceship means. It returns 3 values. and I know how can I invoke it with If statement. `if i>j return 1 elsif i<j return -1 else return 0` isnt it? But my prob is don't know how to use it..

Comment: @Igor sorry for my stupidness..but I didn't lie.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. FINALLY.
I will never forget this.
Thank you everyone who commented.

```
fruits = ["orange", "apple", "banana", "pear", "grapes"]

def sorting(i,j)
  if i>j
      return -1
  elsif i<j
      return 1
  else 
      return 0
  end
end

fruits.sort!{|i,j| sorting(i,j)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
2.1.2 :065 > fruits = ["orange", "apple", "banana", "pear", "grapes"]
 => ["orange", "apple", "banana", "pear", "grapes"]
2.1.2 :066 > fruits.sort! do |i, j|
2.1.2 :067 >     if i > j
2.1.2 :068?>     -1
2.1.2 :069?>     elsif i< j
2.1.2 :070?>     1
2.1.2 :071?>     else
2.1.2 :072?>     0
2.1.2 :073?>     end
2.1.2 :074?>   end
 => ["pear", "orange", "grapes", "banana", "apple"]
```

Comment: thank you! It seems great for me.I wanna vote, but lack of reputation. Forgive me.

Comment: It does not matter, glad I could help.